# Unable to use Abraham Twitter API SDK

Tags: php, api, redirect, twitter

I am using Abraham Twitter API SDK and I am facing some problem while executing index.php page.
in my config.php page my code is like this

```
define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://example.com/callback.php');
```

When, I open the index file in the browser, it redirects to connect.php
Here, if I click on `Signin with PHP` button, the page will redirect to redirect.php
here, my problem comes. In redirect.php page, i am including twitteroauth.php file.

The code in My redirect.php file

```
/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

In my twitteroauth.php file, the constructor is looking like this

```
function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token = NULL, $oauth_token_secret = NULL) {
    $this->sha1_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    if (!empty($oauth_token) && !empty($oauth_token_secret)) {
      $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    } else {
      $this->token = NULL;
    }
  }
```

My error i am getting in the browser is

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in line 80
Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.
```

I tried in many ways to solve this problem. But I failed.
Please help me in that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar error. I solved it by setting a Callback URL in my twitter application settings. http://dev.twitter.com

- Login at https://dev.twitter.com
- Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps
- Click 'Settings' tab
- Set 'Callback URL' as something like http://example.com/twitteroauth/callback.php
- Then save the settings

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error. Can you please explain more on how did you solve the error.

Comment: @ArchitVerma I have edited the above answer. Please check it. Hope it is more clear now.